# Obtener posiciones pares

Tags: java

He intentado eso pero toma los números pares mas no las posiciones pares

```
Arrays.stream("String".split("")).map(NumberUtils::toInt).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).reduce(0, Integer::sum)
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

La lista de elementos pares se puede obtener de la siguiente forma:

```
        var code = "123456";
        IntStream
                .range(0, code.length())
                .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                .mapToObj(i -> code.substring(i, i+1))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Se genera un `Stream` de números, tantos como la longitud de la cadena, de los cuales obtengo los pares y con luego obtengo el correspondiente elemento dentro de la cadena.

Se imprimen los números 1,3,5 que corresponden a las posiciones 0,2,4.

En caso de querer sumar los números obtenidos se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
        var resultado1 = IntStream
                .range(0, code.length())
                .filter(i -> i%2 == 0)
                .mapToObj(i -> code.substring(i, i+1))
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
        System.out.println(resultado1);
```

Decidí reemplazar `NumberUtils::toInt` por `Integer::parseInt` para evitar importar `commons-lang3` más que por otra razón.

Es similar al ejemplo anterior pero esta vez el elemento obtenido de la cadena se convierte a entero y luego se suman los números obtenidos.